# Probability of getting all four answers right, with true and false in each question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose there are 4 questions in total.

Each question has a true/false option.

1) TRUE or FALSE

2) TRUE or FALSE

3) TRUE or FALSE

4) TRUE or FALSE

---

What is the probability of you getting all four questions correct?

I am just curious behind the math, I have not taken a probabiltity course so I'm sure my answer is wrong:

I think that since there are two options per question, the chances of getting 1 question correct is $50/100$. There are four questions in total, so I believe $0.5 \times 4 = 2 = 200\%$

This is obviously false. What is the right answer, and why?

Comment: You don't multiply by 4, you take it to the power of 4

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Sure, whats your math background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each of the four questions, there are two possible outcomes.  Thus, in total, there are $2^4 = 16$ ways to answer the four questions.
\begin{array}{c c c c}
T & T & T & T\\
T & F & T & T\\
T & T & F & T\\
T & F & F & T\\
T & T & T & F\\
T & F & T & F\\
T & T & F & F\\
T & F & F & F\\
F & T & T & T\\
F & F & T & T\\
F & T & F & T\\
F & F & F & T\\
F & T & T & F\\
F & F & T & F\\
F & T & F & F\\
F & F & F & F
\end{array}

Only one of these $16$ sequences is correct.  Assuming each of these $16$ sequences is equally likely to occur (as would result from random guessing), the probability that all four questions are answered correctly is $1/16$.

If we assume that a person is equally likely to guess true or false on each question, then he or she has probability $1/2$ of answering each question correctly.  Under the assumption of [independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)), the probability that all four questions are answered correctly is 
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 = \frac{1}{16}$$
We add probabilities of mutually exclusive events (events that cannot occur at the same time).  We multiply probabilities of independent events.

Answer (score 1):

So the most direct way of telling you what the answer is is this:

For each question you have 1/2 chance of getting the right answer.

Since there are four questions, each has a 1/2 chance of getting the right answer. So to find it, you do (1/2)x(1/2)x(1/2)x(1/2). Therefore, for this case, there is a 1/16 chance of getting the right answer or (1/(2^4)) chance. Or a 6.25% chance.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.